Trying to add dataset in ASP.Net Core but got error
I'm trying to add dataset for RDLC Report using ASP.Net Core but I got this error. With Error in .Net Core
When I try to new project with .Net Framework [enter image description here]it is successful.
Without Error in .Net Framework
Anyone has a solution for this?
